Bluetooth Connecting/Disconnecting
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04. I'm having an issue where both my Xbox controller and Pixel Buds are connecting and disconnecting about every 30-60 seconds. No audio ever comes through the buds, and the controller works with some lag, until it disconnects, of course.
I'm unsure whether this is an issue with my bluetooth antenna or something on the OS level. I'm an electrical engineering student, so I'm not afraid to get into the weeds with this. When I run bluetoothctl from the command line, I see this as the device connects and disconnects:

Is there anywhere I can look to learn how to parse these codes? Looks to me like it has something to do with the bluez package, which makes sense, but the CHG and DEL codes are not clear to me, as well as the hex addresses that it references for delay and volume.
EDIT: I'm an idiot. The desktop had no antennas installed. Would still like to learn more about this terminal output regardless though, if anyone has relevant resources :)

It had to be connecting to something. What other devices do you have that have Bluetooth? A phone?
